# Slow opening of RAW files in wand

Tags: python, thumbnails, wand

I'm using wand *(MagickWand API bindings for Python)* to generate thumbnails of Nikon raw images "file.nef".

Here is part of the code:

```
for arquivo in os.listdir(caminho):

    # Se arquivo termina com
     if arquivo.endswith(".NEF"):

          Inicio = time.time()

          caminho_arquivo = caminho + "/" + arquivo

          with Image(filename=caminho_arquivo) as img:

               Abertura = time.time()

               print("Tempo para abrir: {}".format(int(Abertura - Inicio)))
```

> Tempo para abrir = 12s (time to just open the file!)

Searching the ImageMagick forum I found this:
[http://www.imagemagick.org/](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=30454&p=137628&hilit=raw%20thumbnail&sid=080249d60fc741ed662b9204131d477e#p137628)

If you don't want to open the link here is a resumé:

```
For a file from a Nikon D800 camera, exiftool shows:

 Composite:JpgFromRaw='(Binary data 2307391 bytes, use -b option to extract)'
 Composite:OtherImage='(Binary data 918709 bytes, use -b option to extract)'
 Composite:PreviewImage='(Binary data 101723 bytes, use -b option to extract)'

ImageMagick can't see these images. They can be extracted by exiftool:

exiftool -JpgFromRaw -b AGA_2983.NEF >fromraw.jpg
exiftool -OtherImage -b AGA_2983.NEF >other.jpg
exiftool -PreviewImage -b AGA_2983.NEF >preview.jpg
```

***This exiftool seems to be exactly what I need. Can I use exiftool through Wand?

Are there other options do resolve my problem?***

Thanks!

Comment: ImageMagick uses the libraw delegate library to read RAW formats. See https://www.libraw.org. Install the delegate into ImageMagick and it should allow you to read raw formats from Canon (CRW) and from Nikon (NEF). Once ImageMagick has it installed, it should work form Python Wand. But you might need to preface the image name with NEF:

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstand the link you posted. ImageMagick cannot extract the thumbnail from the raw NEF, but you can read the raw image and create a thumbnail using -thumbnail command.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll take a look into libraw

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  If you could add your solution as an answer (and accept it), that would be awesome.  It helps others find your solution faster.

Comment: @Ricardo Do not add SOLVED to the title of the question, instead post a response and mark it as correct in 2 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> UPDATE! - Problem Solved!

The reason why it was taking so long to load the image was type of file detection. Once I used the code ***format="raw"*** as so:

```
with wand.Image(filename=caminho_arquivo, format="raw") as img:
```

It now took less then a second to process 75 raw files! damn!

I only came across "format=raw" reading the sorce code, it was not in the Doc's.

Anyway, hope this helps someone in the future.